# How do you adjust context-paths with Springdoc OpenAPI & GroupedOpenApi

Tags: springdoc, api-versioning

### Background:

The task that we have is to move from two legacy APIs / services, to consolidate them and to introduce a newer v2 API - that all utilize the same underlying codebase.

My approach has been to utilize multiple `@RestControllers`, each with a class-level `@RequestMapping`. For ease of discussion, assume that the names / sub-paths are:

- `/v1/legacy-api-1`
- `/v1/legacy-api-2`
- `/v2`

I've created three `GroupedOpenApi`'s that correspond to the different sub-paths, and everything looks great in Swagger-UI!

Previously, `legacy-api-1` & `legacy-api-2` have been available through an API manager at distinct endpoints and run as distinct services.

**I'll focus on just `legacy-api-1`...**

So, we'd like to update the API manager to load-balance between the existing versions of the legacy APIs as well as the new consolidated version. For example:

- `{API_MANAGER_BASE_URL}`/`legacy-api-1`

  - `{OLD_LEGACY_API_1_URL}`
  - `{CONSOLIDATED_API_BASE_URL}`/`v1/legacy-api-1`

This is totally feasible.

Where I run into problems is with Swagger-UI, and the generated OpenAPI definitions.

Ideally, I'd love to augment the OpenAPI definition's `servers` collection to be something similar to what exists in the API manager:

- `{API_MANAGER_BASE_URL}`/`legacy-api-1`
- `{OLD_LEGACY_API_1_URL}`
- `{CONSOLIDATED_API_BASE_URL}`/`v1/legacy-api-1`

which is totally doable via `GroupedOpenApi.Builder.addOpenApiCustomiser`.

**However**, all of the operations that are exposed for my API start with `/v1/legacy-api-1/`.

Example:

- `GET` `/v1/legacy-api-1/document` Retrieve document
- `POST` `/v1/legacy-api-1/document` Store document

### Question:

How do I set a `GroupedOpenApi`-specific prefix to remove from the generated OpenAPI definitions / Swagger-UI?

Example (for prefix `/v1/legacy-api-1`):

- `servers`:

  - `{API_MANAGER_BASE_URL}`/`legacy-api-1`
  - `{OLD_LEGACY_API_1_URL}`
  - `{CONSOLIDATED_API_BASE_URL}`/`v1/legacy-api-1` - i.e. the desired "Generated server url"
- operations:

  - `GET` `/document` Retrieve document
  - `POST` `/document` Store document

Or to word the question another way, how do I get a portion of the context-path to be moved from the operations over to the `server` element for a given `GroupedOpenApi`?

Answer (score 0):

After a little more digging I found it in `GroupedOpenApi.builder()` (where `basePath` is something like `/v1/legacy-api-1`):

```java
        .addOpenApiCustomiser(
            oApi -> {
              Paths paths = oApi.getPaths();
              // To avoid ConcurrentModificationException
              String[] keySet = paths.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
              for (String key : keySet) {
                PathItem pathItem = paths.get(key);
                // Remove the basePath from the individual operation
                paths.put(key.replace(basePath, ""), pathItem);
                paths.remove(key);
              }

              Server server = oApi.getServers().get(0);
              // Add the basePath to the server entry
              server.setUrl(server.getUrl() + basePath);
            })
```